# shared_ptr reference counting when spawning a std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm a little new to multithreading in C++11 and I have a specific question on spawning `std::thread`s as shown below. `Notes` is a class with a public method `start` in it. And `thread_list` is a vector holding `std::thread`s.

```
void spawn()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Notes> note = std::make_shared<Notes>();
    std::thread thrd(&Notes::start, note);
    thread_list.push_back(std::move(thrd));
}
```

My question is who owns the `shared_ptr note` after this function finishes? Does reference to the thread `thrd` count as a reference and hence the `shared_ptr` does not destruct the object reference? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read about shared ownership and the semantics of `std::shared_ptr` which is not owned by a single entity. If there are more than one entity which has the same `shared_ptr` (means a *copy* of it, **not** a *reference*), then the *ownership* shared_ptr is shared by all those entities... as such, whoever gets destroyed last, will automatically destroy the shared_ptr as well.

Comment: @Nawaz: I understand how `shared_ptr`s work in general. My question was really specific about usage with std::thread as above.

Comment: shared_ptr doesn't work differently in/across more than one thread, which is why I used the term "entity" in my previous comment, which you can comfortably replace with "thread" if that is going to help you understand your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is who owns the `shared_ptr note` after this function finishes?

`thrd` owns it, in a way. But not really. Read on for what really happens.

> Does reference to the thread `thrd` count as a reference and hence the `shared_ptr` does not destruct the object reference?

Kind of, but not really. `thrd` doesn't actually count as a reference, and actually doesn't share ownership of `note`. It's just a handle to a thread.

So who owns `note`? **The `Notes::start` function does**.

You've started a thread that is executing `Notes::start`, and have passed `notes` to that function. That function now owns `notes`.

If `thrd` goes out of scope, `notes` will still exist so long as the `Notes::start` function hasn't exited and hasn't relinquished ownership of `notes`.

Comment: Gotcha! Perfect! Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The function `Notes::start` may not even be running when `spawn()` returns. What happens instead is that a `std::function` object is created from `Notes::start` and that object is then bound with the shared pointer. This bound function is part of the `thread` instance. Of course, when calling the function, the refcount will probably increment again. BTW: I'm assuming that the function takes a `shared_ptr` by value or by reference, if any implicit conversions take place, different things may happen.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Are you referring to the usage such as `std::thread thrd(std::bind(&Notes::start, note))` ? Will a std::function object be created with the C++11 std::thread constructor too? I see no mention of this in any references.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the thread constructor isn't defined based on `std::bind()`. If you look at the wording of the two though, you will find a lot of similarities, and in practice there is no difference.